# Homemade Truffle Salt

Tags: salt, truffles

How do you make truffle salt at home? I tried with just a jarred black truffle I got at the stores. I finely grated it over a microplane and then mixed it with salt and let it sit for a while. It doesn't taste at all like the truffle salt I buy at the store. I can't find anything online either. What kind of truffles do I get? What do you look for? How do I prep them? What is the ratio of salt to truffle? What are the instructions? Thank you.

Comment: white truffle salts are around the 6-10% white truffle range.  i would assume black truffle salts are roughly the same.

Comment: Because truffles have a fairly volatile aroma, all commercial truffle salt that I have seen has added aroma extracts (natural or synthetic) and it would be hard to duplicate that unless you can find a source of the extracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The process is apparently very simple: grate fresh truffle into salt using a microplane, and pulse with a food processor to blend.**  [One source](http://luxirare.com/black-truffles-all-day/) said the flavor intensified over time. I can't find a ratio either, but it looks like about 10:1 salt:truffle, maybe less.

**Flavor is always going to vary a bit with something natural such as truffles**, but if your result tastes *nothing* like store truffle salt, there's a couple possible reasons.  Perhaps the truffles you're using aren't *truly* fresh.  I suspect the store truffle salt adds flavor extracts or synthetic truffle oil to punch up the flavor a bit. Stuff derived from real truffles is often milder but more complex than things using synthetic imitations.

Finally, you might try using a different salt.  I'd suggest the best sea salt you can get your hands on. Rougher salt grains might absorb flavor oils better than more regular ones, and better sea salts add their own subtle tastes.

Comment: What kind of truffle should I be using? And how do I get my hands on a fresh truffle? And how do I know if a truffle isn't fresh?

Comment: @anton2g Depends on what kind of truffle you want to flavor it with... if you're in the US you might be able to get Oregon truffles cheaper and fresher than (for example) the higher-end imported black winter truffles.  Fresh truffle is hard to find, I can't help you there.  You either need to know somebody, or pay a fortune for it, possibly purchasing in advance.  The last place I saw it for sale was a dedicated truffle guy who would make rounds at local restaurants on his return from Europe. Depending on the variety of truffle, you'll need it in season, and it loses flavor in mere days.

Comment: Should the truffles used be fresh, dried, frozen, or what?

Comment: @anton2g Oh, it's a given that fresh truffle is preferred for the best flavor.  You might be able to get away with frozen, at the cost of the more subtle flavors.  I would not mess with the dried or canned/preserved truffles for this use; both will need additional processing to regain some of their flavor, and won't achieve their peak in this fashion.